# IIS URL Rewrite and ajax calls in Asp.NET Core 2.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a Asp.NET Core 2.2 site at localhost:81 and I have set up a IIS URL Rewrite to make it accessible from

```
www.mydomain.com/mysite
```

*Note: I have other sites located on other ports on localhost which are published the same way.*

The URL Rewriter takes care of rewriting the references in `.cshtml` files, but it doesn't handle my ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Customers/Index?handler=HairColor&customerID=@Model.CustomerID&date=" + myDate,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    data: null,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {},
    failure: function(response) {}
});
```

I don't know how the rewrite module could ever know that it should rewrite that specific url in my javascript.

**Question:**
What is the right way to make the ajax call compatible with my website setup?

---

*I am starting to wonder if hosting multiple sites like this on a single domain 
is the wrong approach?*